# Windows 10 - Vagrant 1.9.2 - Hyper-V Provider - Hyper-V provider requires that Vagrant be run with administrative priviledges

Tags: vagrant, hyper-v

I'm trying to run `vagrant up --provider=hyperv` and I get the error:

"The provider 'hyperv' that was requested to back the machine
'default' is reporting that it isn't usable on this system. The
reason is shown below:

The Hyper-V provider requires that Vagrant be run with
administrative privileges. This is a limitation of Hyper-V itself.
Hyper-V requires administrative privileges for management
commands. Please restart your console with administrative
privileges and try again."

I am already running the command line with administrative privileges. How can I run vagrant with administrative privileges from the command line?

Comment: Did you actually start your console as administrator (right-click on `Command Prompt` and choose *Run as Administrator*)? It's not enough to just open a command prompt while logged in as an admin; you have to specifically open that console as one.

Comment: Yes, exactly, I right-clicked Command Prompt and choose Run as Administrator

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Niles, you did nothing wrong. Its a known error that will be corrected in VAGRANT 1.9.5.

> "Fixed admin test to verify that you are running in an elevated shell, not that you are in the administrators group since that is not required."
>   https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/pull/8510

If you dont want to wait you can implement the fix manually by implementing [THESE](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/pull/8510/commits/80bced202b1ee09eb8cfd3341717b6530c4a0cf5) changes.

Comment: Where do I implement these changes? The release of vagrant I got from scoop seems to just be a single exe, and I can't see anywhere nightlies are released.

Comment: Is there a workaround until 9.5 is released? Maybe an older version of Vagrant that worked with HyperV? or a way to download nightly Vagrant Windows builds?

Comment: @sbrother Found the docs on installing Vagrant from source: https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/installation/source.html. If you're on Windows and don't have Ruby, installing via [`scoop`](http://scoop.sh/) is painless and leaves your system clean when uninstalled.

Comment: Thanks @AsadSaeeduddin!

Answer (score -1):

To solve this, run "regedit"

Go to "Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Session Manager\Environment"

Set "_PSLockdownPolicy" = "8"